# Display each array list element in turn when a button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I made a `JFrame` using Java.

I am given an `arraylist =[1,2,3,4]` and whenever I click the next button the next number in list should get displayed in `JLabel`.
I have written the code but the problem is that it displays **"1"** when I run the file and when i click the next button it shows **4** in the label. **2 and 3** are not getting shown.

How can I resolve the issue?

```
public class prac extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ArrayList<Integer>arr=new ArrayList<>();
        

    /**
     * Creates new form prac
     */
    
    public prac() {
        initComponents();
        arr.add(1);
        arr.add(2);
        arr.add(3);
        arr.add(4);
        String s=String.valueOf(arr.get(0));
        jLabel1.setText(s);
    }
    
    

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("next");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 281, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(124, 124, 124)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 86, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(81, 81, 81))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        //System.out.println(lis);
        int i;
        
        for(i=1;i<arr.size();i++)
        {
            String d=String.valueOf(arr.get(i));
           jLabel1.setText(d);
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(prac.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(prac.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(prac.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(prac.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new prac().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

After running the file

[image]

After clicking next

[image]

Comment: `jButton1ActionPerformed` goes through the whole list and sets the value each iteration so it will always only end on the last one.

Comment: jLabel1.setText(d); is inside your for loop so it is changing your value every iteration.

Comment: @takendarkk yes exactly thats what is happening...how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

#### To just run through 1-4

As stated in the comments, your `for` loop in the `jButton1ActionPerformed` method in incorrect. You should just:

- take existing value
- increase by one
- reset to 1 if exceeds the limit

  ```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       int limit = arr.size(); //or just 4?
       String d=jLabel.getText(); //take old one
       //if no value was set before..
       if (d.length()==0) d = "0";
       int num = Integer.parseInt(d) + 1; //takes next one
       if (num>limit) num = 1; //resets to 1 if needed
       jLabel1.setText(""+num);
   }
  ```

#### To take values from ArrayList

To take from `ArrayList` the plan is similar, but instead of just +1, you:

- find index of old value in the List,
- increase index by one,
- reset to 0 if out of bounds,
- set text of JLabel to the value of List at the new index

.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String d = jLabel1.getText(); //take from old one
    //if no value was set before, just sets to -1, so after +1 would be at idx 0
    if (d.length()==0) d = "-1";
    int parsedOldValue = Integer.parseInt(d); //gets int from String
    int newIndex = arr.indexOf(parsedOldValue) + 1; //takes next index
    if (newIndex >= arr.size()) newIndex = 0; //if exceeds, takes 0th
    jLabel1.setText(""+arr.get(newIndex));
}
```

Comment: It did not work.It is displaying just the first element of arraylist

Comment: @151_ANKITASAHA - I edited 2nd to last line `l.size()` changed to `arr.size()`. I also tested the code and it has to work if applied correctly. Both options are looping through the options. Can you tell which of my options is failing for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to loop through the numbers 1 through 4, you don't need an array at all. You only need to read the current value of the label and increment it, changing it back to 1 if it would increment to 5.

```
private static void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(jLabel1.getText());
    i++;
    if (i == 5) i = 1;
    jLabel1.setText(i.toString());
}
```

However, if you really need to read the values from an array because it might not be sequential, you can look up the current value in the array and increment the index.

```
private static void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(jLabel1.getText());
    int index = arr.indexOf(i);
    index++;
    if (index == 3) index = 0;
    jLabel1.setText(arr.get(index).toString());
}
```

*Note: The second method will not work if there are duplicate values in the array.*